# Insert text in each row of mysql field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with this structure :

```
ID | IMG
_____________
1  | img.jpg
2  | otherimg.png
3  | img2.png 
4  | someimg.gif
5  | otherelseimg.jpg
6  | dummy.jpg
7  | jusimg.jpg
```

How can I modified each row to become like this :

```
ID | IMG
_____________
1  | folder/img.jpg
2  | folder/otherimg.png
3  | folder/img2.png 
4  | folder/someimg.gif
5  | folder/otherelseimg.jpg
6  | folder/dummy.jpg
7  | folder/jusimg.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** since you are using `MySQL`.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    IMG = CONCAT('folder/', IMG)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CONCAT() function in mysql. which is used to concatenate two or more strings

```
update <table>
set IMG=concat('folder/',IMG)
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c413/1)